# Use value in new variable name

Tags: r

I am trying to build a for loop which will step through each site, for that site calculate frequencies of a response, and put those results in a new data frame. Then after the loop I want to be able to combine all of the site data frames so it will look something like:

```
Site     Genus     Freq
1        A         50
1        B         30
1        C         20
2        A         70
2        B         10
2        C         20
```

But to do this I need my names (of vectors, dataframes) to change each time through the loop. I think I can do this using the SiteNum variable, but how do I insert it into new variable names? The way I tried (below) treats it like part of the string, doesn't insert the value for the name.

I feel like what I want to use is a placeholder %, but I don't know how to do that with variable names.

```
> SiteNum <- 1
> for (Site in CoralSites){
    > Csub_SiteNum <- subset(dfrmC, Site==CoralSites[SiteNum]) 
    > CGrfreq_SiteNum <- numeric(length(CoralGenera))
    > for (Genus in CoralGenera){
        > CGrfreq_SiteNum[GenusNum] <- mean(dfrmC$Genus == CoralGenera[GenusNum])*100
        > GenusNum <- GenusNum + 1
        > }
    > names(CGrfreq_SiteNum) <- c(CoralGenera)
    > Site_SiteNum <- c(Site)
    > CG_SiteNum <- data.frame(CoralGenera,CGrfreq_SiteNum,Site_SiteNum)
    > SiteNum <- SiteNum + 1
    > }
```

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: The asterisks make your code harder to read. I would take them out. The command you're looking for is paste, but I can't easily see where it would go.

Comment: Well the output would be one dataframe for each site, named "CG_1, CG_2, etc," which I would then join into one dataframe with all sites.

Answer (score 0):

Your question as stated asks how you can create a bunch of variables, e.g. `CGrfreq_1`, `CGrfreq_2`, ..., where the name of the variable indicates the site number that it corresponds to (1, 2, ...). While you can do such a thing with functions like `assign`, it is not good practice for a few reasons:

1. It makes your code to generate the variables more complicated because it will be littered with calls to `assign` and `get` and `paste0`.
2. It makes your data more difficult to manipulate afterwards -- you'll need to (either manually or programmatically) identify all the variables of a certain type, grab their values with `get` or `mget`, and then do something with them.

Instead, you'll find it easier to work with other R functions that will perform the aggregation for you. In this case you're looking to generate for each Site/Genus pairing the percentage of data points at the site with the particular genus value. This can be done in a few lines of code with the `aggregate` function:

```
# Sample data:
(dat <- data.frame(Site=c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)), Genus=c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 6), "A")))
#    Site Genus
# 1     1     A
# 2     1     A
# 3     1     A
# 4     1     B
# 5     1     B
# 6     2     B
# 7     2     B
# 8     2     B
# 9     2     B
# 10    2     A

# Calculate frequencies
dat$Freq <- 1
res <- aggregate(Freq~Genus+Site, data=dat, sum)
res$Freq <- 100 * res$Freq / table(dat$Site)[as.character(res$Site)]
res
#   Genus Site Freq
# 1     A    1   60
# 2     B    1   40
# 3     A    2   20
# 4     B    2   80
```